# jenkins error while execute sonarqube scanner with freestyle pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

[jenkins error while execute sonarqube scanner with freestyle pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90dwx.jpg)

I have installed the sonarqube plugin and have added sonarqube-token

it's a freestyle-pipeline
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buzKW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtZ9P.png)

Comment: First of all there is no such thing as a "freestyle pipeline". It is either a "scripted" or a "declaraive" pipeline or it is a "freestyle job". From just the screenshot it is hard to guess which one.

Please add more details:
- which job type
- how does your pipeline script or freestyle steps look like
- do you have a `sonar-project.properties` file or similar for configuration, how does it look like?

Comment: it's a freestyle pipeline

Comment: i have sonar-project.properties in my workspace pipeline

Comment: Never used the plugin, but it clearly says (in Orange) that there is no credential with the id `sonarqube-token`. You should probably create the credentials like here: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/analyzing-source-code/ci-integration/jenkins-integration/#sonarqube-scanner-plugin

Or if it is anyway an unsecured on-premise solution you can probably enable unauthorized access (with care).